# невозможно создать дамп _asyncio.Future объектов

Tags: python, telegram, asyncio, pickle, telethon

Пользуюсь библиотекой telethon, всё было отлично, ровно до того момента как я захотел создать дамп сообщения, когда я пытаюсь это сделать, выбрасывает ошибку can't pickle `_asyncio.Future objects`, кто подскажет как с этим бороться?
код:

```
client = TelegramClient('telegram', CONST.TG_API_ID, CONST.TG_API_HASH)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def message_log(event: events.NewMessage.Event):
    msg = pickle.dumps(event.message)

with client.start():
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: ваш код смешивает синхронный и асинхронные стили. Благодаря "магии" это работает для некоторых методов. Если вы только начинаете с telethon (работаете с >=1.0 версией), то используйте асинхронный стиль везде (будет очевидно, почему  писать Future на диск просто так не имеет смысла)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, `Message` наследует `Future`. Вам придётся получить из `event.message` интересующие вас поля, сохранить их в какую-либо структуру, поддерживающую сериализацию, и дампить уже её:

```
msg = pickle.dumps({
    'text': event.message.message,
    'from': event.message.from_id,
})
```

Comment: Замечательно! Но хотелось бы чтоб я сохранял именно экземпляр класса message, так как там может быть не только текст, но и картинка и геолокация и вообще много чего.

Comment: И всё это вам придётся предварительно извлечь, так как `Message` сериализовать невозможно в силу его асинхронной природы.